# Smooth transition between loaded pages on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to recreate the following "effect" for my portfolio but I've been out of web development for a while and I can't find my way around it. Hopefully someone here can give me a hint.

I'm trying to achieve a kind of smooth transition between pages as you can see for example on those websites.

www. say.studio/
cedricklachot. com
www.durimel. io

(sorry I know is not the right way to put links but I don't know how to put them, it's constantly giving me error messages when I paste the URLs and it's driving me mad!)

When you switch from one page to another it feels like everything is on the same page, because it's so smooth and navigation elements remain on place, like it's just one single html file for the whole website and the rest of stuff is loaded by javascript, but as I see from the URLs there are different pages, so it must be switching between different html files. But this "smooth switching" so to say is what I can't find the way to replicate.

I have tried with onload animations like fading in effects, but still it's very clear that the browser is switching between different html pages so it definitely doesn't have the smoothness that I see on the examples I provided.

I hope I explained myself well as I'm not native English speaker :) thanks

Comment: `but as I see from the URLs there are different pages, so it must be switching between different html files.`

Not true, frameworks like angular can do this with one html file, but switching components within that file. Angular updates the URL bar so you can navigate and gives you the feel of multiple pages.

Comment: Yes, lots of frameworks doing this these days, Vue Router also makes navigation seamless, Gatsby and I suppose other static site generators, React...You can achieve seamless navigation with all of those and I suspect many others. If that is your main goal, to have a site that is really fast and can navigate in a seamless way, I'd recommend a static site generator probably. You can of course, achieve that in a traditional website by using "tabs" and not real navigation, hide "pages" in divs that are hidden, etc, but that's just a "trick"

Comment: Thanks for the answers!! I'll try to take a look at them and see if I can figure out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Welsome to Stack Overflow. React framework is good for this, the page re-renders with updated components when a user changes it. You can also use php for this, which is a more primitive version in my opinion.

here's a cool app. i use Wappalyzer for firefox, it lets you see what technologies. the page is using, when i examine your link

well this one doesnt work https://www.say.studio/cedricklachot.com

this one https://www.durimel.io/nel

uses PHP on an apache server.

So view the source code, then you're going to have to learn PHP (Or copy and edit it)

the server is going to be tricky if you don't have experience. I'd recommend using AWS EC2, and doing an ubuntu build with Apache (or Nginx)

let us know when its finished : )